# how to understand the permissible voltage and current of film capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current-limiting

I use the *0.12uF* metallized polyester film capacitor Model *ECQE2124JB* which 
has *250VDC* rated voltage. I have a sine wave across the capacitor, then can I 
think that the maximum AC voltage is **250/1.414=176.8 Vrms**? But from the characteristic datasheet, the permissible voltage is less than *40Vrms* at sinewave. What's the difference? If I use the capacitor in a LC resonant circuit, does it mean the RMS resonant voltage cannot exceed *40Vrms*?
In my opinion, the permissible current is calculated as **I = 2*pi*f*C*V**, for my application f = 10KHz, so **I = 2*3.14*10kHz*0.12uF*250V=1.884Ap = 1.33Arms**. Is it right? But from the characteristic datasheet, the permissible current is only about *0.2Arms*. Why that?
In my LC resonant application, the mearsured current across the capacitor reaches *3.5Arms*, but the peak voltage will not exceed *250VDC*. It also conflicts with **Vrms = Irms *Xc**, where *Xc* is the impedance of the capacitor.

https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/capacitors/film-capacitors/film-cap-electroequip/ecqeb-dc-rated/ECQE2124JB
[image]

Comment: You can't exceed the permissible voltage *or* the permissible current or your capacitor might die. It's that simple. Really.

Answer (score 1):

Excess voltage will cause the capacitor to fail due to dielectric breakdown.

Excess current will cause the capacitor to fail due to overheating (because of the equivalent series resistance of the capacitor). Since an AC voltage implies an AC current as the capacitor charges and discharges, an AC voltage can lead to overheating failure at a lower voltage than the DC voltage that would cause dielectric breakdown.

So you have two different failure mechanisms, and you need to consider different limitations to avoid these two types of failure.

Comment: So the applied AC voltage and current (for example, a sinewave) should not exceed the "Permissible Voltage" and "Permissible Current", while some other kind of voltage (for example, DC or pulse) should not exceed the rated VDC like 250V?